# Calculating month differences in pyspark between timestamp and a string

Tags: date, pyspark

I am using pyspark in databricks with a JSON file to clean data. The expression in the `eval` brackets comes from the JSON file.

One of the issues I am facing is manipulating `timestamp`s/`string`.

I am trying to find the difference in months between a timestamp column and a single date (which is a string)

See code below.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df2 = df2.withColumn('test', eval("months_between( F.to_date(F.col('period_name')), lit('31/03/2019'))"))
```

It doesn't throw an error but evaluates to null.

Comment: [Using `eval` is generally bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). I don't see any need for it in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `eval` query to:

```
df2 = df2.withColumn('test', eval("months_between(F.to_date(F.col('period_name')), F.to_date(F.lit('31/03/2019'), 'dd/MM/yyyy'))"))
```

This should convert the literal string column to datetype too.

If your `date` string is not `yyyy-MM-dd`, then you will need to specify the format.

Comment: Thanks this does work but weirdly I had to change the order of my date to yyyy-mm-dd otherwise it would still return null

Comment: @Tiger_Stripes I have updated my answer to include date format

Comment: Why use `eval` at all? Why not just: `df2.withColumn('test',F.months_between(F.to_date(F.col('period_name')), F.to_date(F.lit('31/03/2019'), 'dd/MM/yyyy'))))`

Comment: @pault He says that the query/code is coming as a string from a json object.

Comment: but your answer modified the expression inside the `eval` which means that OP can do the same, which means they can avoid using `eval` altogether.

Comment: @pault It’s possible it could be coming from another process. It’s mentioned in the question, so it’s same to assume it could be a constraint

Answer (score 2):

[Using `eval` is bad practice.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) I see no need for it in this case.

You can maintain the flexibility of reading the query from a `json` file using [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) instead

```
df2 = df2.withColumn(
    'test', 
    expr("months_between(to_date(period_name), to_date('31/03/2019', 'dd/MM/yyyy'))")
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give changing it a go to expr instead of eval